# Error Using Load, Can't Read File in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm a Matlab rookie and totally stumped by this: I'm trying to use "load" to read two .mat files. One works fine. When I use "load '/home/filepath/file2.mat'" to load the other, I get

```
Error using load
Can't read file
```

If I check with "exist file2.mat" or "exist file1.mat", I see "ans = 2" (same thing with full file path). They have the same permissions and are of similar sizes. Any ideas as to what could be going on here?

I built the .mat files in Python, so it is certainly possible the file itself is the source of the problem. I used scipy, specifically:

```
scipy.io.savemat('./file2.mat', mdict={'WO_scopus': np.asarray(all_unique_word, dtype='object').reshape(len(all_unique_word), 1)})
scipy.io.savemat("./file1.mat", mdict={"AN_scopus":np.asarray(all_unique_author, dtype='object').reshape(len(all_unique_author), 1)})
```

"whos -file file2.mat" produces

```
  Name                Size               Bytes  Class    Attributes

  WO_scopus      137119x1             17711126  cell
```

which seems correct.

Comment: We definitely need more information in order to help you here. Post Matlab's output? Where did you get the .mat files from?

Comment: @MattTaylor - added some more info, let me know if there's a way for me to provide anything more useful

Comment: The file is called `file2.mat`, not `file2`. Use the right name when loading.

Comment: @CodyBraun: I saw that you updated your question fixing the missing question as a reaction to my comment. Please provide the code exactly as you use it, including the successful calls of `whos` and `exist`

Comment: Which library do you use to write the mat file?

Comment: @Daniel Yeah, sorry about that- I just used "exist file2.mat", which yields "ans = 2". Same thing with "exist /home/filepath/file2.mat". I used scipy, specifically "scipy.io.savemat('./file2.mat', mdict={'WO_scopus': np.asarray(all_unique_word, dtype='object').reshape(len(all_unique_word), 1)})"

Comment: You need to edit this new info into your question. Were both *.mat files produced by the same code?

Comment: Do minimal examples work (e.g. writing an integer using scipy)? Try writing only a small part of the array, maybe it is a special element causing the problem.

Comment: Using a smaller subset of the data to build the .mat files, they load fine. So it looks like you may be correct; perhaps there is some encoding issue related to a particular element in the .mat files. I'll see if I can find exactly where the cutoff is where this quits loading

Comment: Does the issue still exists? If so add the relevant details, otherwise please write a short answer how you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was an encoding issue on the larger dataset, though I would've expected a more specific error from MatLab. I fixed this by iterating over my output list in the Python script and using .encode('utf-8') before sending to savemat.